# How do you open StringIO in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, io, sinatra, pry

I have a Sinatra application with the following `main.rb`:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

get '/' do
  @@p = Pry.new
  haml :index
end

post '/' do
  code = params[:code]

  $stdout = StringIO.new

  @@p.eval(code)
  output = $stdout.string

  $stdout = STDOUT

  output_arr = []
  output.each_line('\n') { |line| output_arr << line }

  output_arr[1]

  binding.pry
end
```

When I hit the `binding.pry` at the bottom to see if `output` contains any output, it seems like the IO stream is not closed, as I can't get anything to show up in the console.

However if I try to call `open` on `StringIO.new`, I receive an `NoMethodError - private method 'open' called`.

I am requiring 'stringio' in a `config.ru` file, and I've also tried requiring it in the `main.rb` file:

`config.ru`:

```
require 'stringio'
require './main'
run Sinatra::Application
```

I'm not sure if this is related but something interesting that I've noticed is that, in `irb`, if I `require 'pry'` before requiring `stringio`, then it returns `false`, otherwise it returns `true`.

This makes me wonder if Sinatra is including `Pry` from my Gemfile before loading the `config.ru`. Could that be the problem? Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `StringIO#open`? What are you trying to do? If you replace `binding.pry` with a simple `puts` statement, does stdout work then?

Comment: I'm trying to look capture stdout from the `eval` line and store it in the `output_arr` for further processing. The puts statement works when I restart the server, but after the initial call to `eval` it breaks and gives me a `IOError - not opened for writing` error.